# Send and receive money, payment gateway with Golang

Tags: transactions, go-lang

I'm really newbie with bitcoin development, so I would like to use go for that, so

1. what I need for?
2. What libraries can I use for send and receive money, easy and secure?
3. Are there any examples?
4. I would like to do it that support user concurrency, How can I do it?

Comment: Hey Cristian, welcome to Bitcoin.SE. I don't understand your question one and four, could you please explain better what you want to do? "Payment gateway" does leave a lot of things open to interpretation. ;)

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you done any research yourself? https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/API_reference_(JSON-RPC)#Go

Comment: @m1xolyd1an Thanks for the example, but,  the credentials in the example are from where?

Comment: It's does mean that I need to setup my own bitcoin rpc server, really?

Comment: RPC is one option. You could also try a 3rd party API service. One an example would be blockcypher as they have libraries in golang. I am not making any recommendation for or against them, it's just an example.

Comment: Any updates on this?

Answer (score 1):

There is a Bitcoin client implemented in Go called [btcd](https://github.com/btcsuite/btcd) which you might want to check out. This should allow you to send and receive money, if you read more about it, I'm sure you'll find plenty of examples.

Comment: It's does mean that I need to setup my own `bitcoin rcp server`, and after that I can develop my application using `btcrpcclient`, really?

Comment: If I'll develop a concurrent application, the recommendation is setup multiples `bitcoin rpc servers` and use load balancer or something similar to  serve de transactions, or what do you thing that is better for architecture?